# Cantidad de Cursores Abiertos en SQL SERVER 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, cursor

alguien tiene idea de cómo verificar la cantidad de cursores abiertos en una base de datos SQL SERVER 2000?

Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Revisa en el performance monitor al menos para 2012 hay una metrica llamada "Cursos Manager by Type". Ahi esta un total para active cursors.